# Import error when executing standalone exe created with nuitka

Tags: python, nuitka

I am trying to create a standalone exe from python code using nuitka. Its a rather sizable program with several libraries including for instance PyQt5.

I have created the exe using:`python -m nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --enable-plugin=qt-plugins --enable-plugin=numpy --python-flag=no_site --mingw64 rs_main.py`

I have also tried without the `--mingw64` and `--python-flag=no_site` flags but they all give me the same error when I try to execute the resulting exe:
`ImportError: LoadLibraryEx 'D:\... ...\rs_main.dist\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd' failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

I checked and the file does exist in the correct location.

The compiling itself gives me some warnings but no errors.

Online I found my problem here: https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/73 but to be honest I do not fully understand their journey towards the solution and as I think I understand it should be solved in my version of nuitka which is 0.6.6. On top of that I am running python 3.7.3 on a windows 10 machine.

Hopefully someone can explain me the solution in the referenced link or offer one of their own. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not really an answer to my question, but if anyone comes across this question, maybe my solution is good enough for them as well.

So although I know it does not do the same as Nuitka I was finally able to create a standalone exe using **pyinstaller** including some flags such as `--hidden-imports` and add the path to Qt but I found the feedback of pyinstaller to be rather understandable.

So maybe if you have the same problem as me, this might be a different approach for you as well.